# Is it "LEGAL" or USED in real life to place a class/struct inside of a class/struct?

Tags: swift, class, struct

```
struct Shape{
var length: Float = 0
var width: Float = 0

struct Rectange {
    var length = Shape().length
    var width = Shape().width

    var area: Float{
        get{
            return length * width
        }
    }


}   
}
```

I know how to assign values from one struct to a nested struct. I just want to see if this IS USED or "LEGAL" in real life.

Comment: What do you mean with "LEGAL"? It does compile so it's probably LEGAL ;)

Comment: I mean like, do people actually do this in real life. Are programmers using this strategy? @appzYourLife

Comment: `String.CharacterView`, `Calendar.Identifier` are examples in the Swift standard library.

Comment: Nesting type definitions is not a replacement for *subclassing* if that is what you are thinking of. You have just defined two (more or less unrelated) types `Shape` and `Shape.Rectangle`.

Comment: Yes. It's fine. Why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely used in real life. Apple even recommends this in one of their sample code examples. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/LucidDreams/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: It would make sense to have type `Shape`, type `Rect`, and type `Circle` and place `Rect` and `Circle` under `Shape`?

Comment: Well, that would depend on what you were trying to do. The advantage of nesting these types is that it is sometimes easier to reason about things in this way. In that sample code you see a lot of enums that are defined within classes because they are used within those classes. I'm not sure if your case fits that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this approach is used in real life.

Look at this example (here I'm using an enum but we can imagine similar examples for structs and classes)

```
struct Spaceship {
    enum Speed {
        case warp, light
    }
    let maxSpeed: Speed
}

struct Airplane {
    enum Speed {
        case subsonic, supersonic
    }
    let maxSpeed: Speed
}
```

Both structs have a `Speed` type defined inside them. Since the `Speed` enum is defined inside the namespace of `Spaceship` and `Airplane` there is no naming collision and everything is pretty clear.

Comment: Okay, I sort of see where your heading. My example is like if you have a type `Shape` , type `Rectangle`, and type `Square`. That would also make sense to put those two types inside `Shape`? @appzYourLife

Comment: @FusionPointInc: I updated my answer, please take a look.

Comment: Yeah I understand, but I mean't if you placed that Airplane under Spaceship, is that still practiced? It doesn't matter if you have values or not.